# Calling java applets via NPAPI / NPRuntime in Chromium

Tags: java, npapi, chromium, npruntime

I found this bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=580#c69
stating that Chromium doesn't support LiveConnect.

One of the developers responded with

> We don't ever intend to support LiveConnect in Chrome.  The newest
>   version of the Java  plugin from Sun removes the need for this, since
>   it uses NPRuntime to allow scripting.

Does anyone know how to make calls to/from java applets and javascript using the NPAPI / NPRuntime interface?  Just a simple example or resource would suffice.

Comment: I don't know this for sure, but I would guess it works the same way that it did with LiveConnect.  the details should be abstracted in the plugin.